# Querying an Oracle Database via Php Script: Insufficient Privileges

Tags: php, oracle

I'm trying to query a remote Oracle database through a PHP script. I'm running WAMP server. The Oracle database is read only. I have no problem connecting using the PHP script but I get errors on the oci_execute command.

This is the script I use:

```
<?php

$c = oci_connect("username", "password", "oracle_SID");

if (!$c) {
$e = oci_error();
trigger_error('Could not connect to database: '. $e['message'],E_USER_ERROR);
}

$s = oci_parse($c, 'Select * from fdma.t_title_stage');
if (!$s) {
    $e = oci_error($c);
    trigger_error('Could not parse statement: '. $e['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}

$r = oci_execute($s);
if (!$r) {
$e = oci_error($s);
trigger_error('Could not execute statement: '. $e['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);

?>
```

These are the errors I'm getting when I run the script:
[image]

If the database is read-only I should be able to run a `select *` query against it, right?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has no concept of a database being "read-only". The user you're connecting with may not have any create/insert/update/delete rights, which would make the database read-only to this user, but it's a property of the user, not the database.

The error you're getting, in conjunction with the sql statement (`... from fdma.t_title_stage`) seems like you're connecting with a user that doesn't even have select rights on fdma's `t_title_stage` table. Try loggin in as `fdma`, the `grant select on t_title_stage to xxx` with `xxx` being the `username` you're using in your oci_connect statement.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I checked the oracle database and the user does have the rights to select.